# C++ memcpy/strcpy of char pointer to class member char pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, strcpy, char-pointer

i have a custom class, let's call it "Student" and a main method. I'm instanciating the class, and just want to output the content of the class.

My programm crashes with a: `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

### Actual Code

Student.h

```cpp
#ifndef PROG2_STUDENT_H
#define PROG2_STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>

class Student
{
private:
    char *name;

    char *firstName;

    unsigned matriculationNumber;

    unsigned semester;

public:
    Student(char *name, char *firstName, unsigned matriculationNumber, unsigned semester);

    ~Student();

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &ostream, const Student &student);
private:
};

#endif
```

Student.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student(char *name, char *firstName, unsigned matriculationNumber, unsigned semester)
{
    std::strcpy(this->name, name);
    std::strcpy(this->firstName, firstName);

    this->matriculationNumber = matriculationNumber;
    this->semester            = semester;
}

Student::~Student()
{
    delete[] this->name;
    delete[] this->firstName;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Student &input)
{
    stream << input.name << ", " << input.firstName << ": "
           << input.semester << " Semester, MA " << input.matriculationNumber;

    return stream;
}
```

and my main

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "StudentPackage/Collection/StudentCollection.h"

int main()
{
    Student studentOne((char *)"Testerson", (char *)"Test", 12345, 2);
    std::cout << studentOne << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### What i have tried

I have tried several things, including memcpy. But with memcpy I'm not able to detect the size of the char array correctly.

When i change the Student Constructor to the following, i get problems with the delete/free in the destructor. I guess, this isn't the correct way anyway, but this is happening, because the scope of the input variables are destroyed before the class destructor is called, correct?

```cpp
Student::Student(char *name, char *firstName, unsigned matriculationNumber, unsigned semester)
{
    this->name      = name;
    this->firstName = firstName;

    this->matriculationNumber = matriculationNumber;
    this->semester            = semester;
}
```

### Question

1. How can i correctly copy the char array from constructor (name to this->name)?
2. How can i correctly copy the char array from constructor (firstName to this->firstName)?

Comment: You forgot to allocate any memory.

Comment: The parameters should be `const char*`, not `char*`. (I suspect that you got a compilation error, but fixed it in the wrong place.)

Comment: 1) Even if `std::strcpy` allocated memory, you should never use `delete[]` on anything that was not obtained with `new T[n]`. 2) Use `std::string`.

Comment: But why the (const char*)? What if i want to implement a method like: `changeName(char* newName)`? Would this be fine to declare `const char* newName` as well?

Comment: @Evg i would love to use std::string, but this is a instruction of my professor ^^ I have to build around this. But what to you mean with `new T[n]`? Why do i need a `new` operator in here?

Comment: If you want to manage memory manually, you have several possibilities, but allocation and deallocation functions should always match each other. If you allocate with `new`, you use `delete`, if you allocate with `new[]`, you use `delete[]`, if you allocate with `malloc()`, you use `free()`. `std::strcpy()` doesn't allocate memory: it is your responsibility to provide a buffer that is large enough, i.e. you should first initialize `this->name` with something meaningful. Don't forget about the space for the terminating null character.

Comment: *Would this be fine to declare `const char* newName` as well?* - Yes if `changeName(x)` is not supposed to modify the buffer pointed at by `x`, and I guess it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::strcpy` does not allocate memory. So your program is copying input to a "garbage" address that is occurred in the memory area where your `Student` object is placed. And as result no surprise that you are getting segment violation as result. There are two solutions:

- a "C-style" way - allocate memory manually (i.e. like `auto n = std::strlen(name); this->name = new char[n + 1]; std::strcpy(this->name, name);`), but then you need to delete it manually (i.e. `delete name;`) in the destructor. btw, `n + 1` because you also need room for the null-terminator, `strlen` result does not include it.
- much better and more "C++" way - use `std::string` (i.e. declate `name` member variable as `std::string`). Then you just can do an asignment: `this->name = name;`, and no need manual memory management - `std::string` will take care.
- (Code style) Also recommend to use some prefix or postfix for member variables, i.e. like `m_name`(more "Microsoft" style), or `name_` - more "Google" style, to avoid those unnecessary `this->`.